# Google Big Query does not work on Azure DevOps hosted ubuntu agent

Tags: google-cloud-platform, azure-devops, google-bigquery

My `Azure DevOps` pipeline runs on hosted `ubuntu 16.04` agent.

The first bash script installs `Google SDK`. Then:

`gcloud auth activate-service-account`

Activated service account credentials for:

`gcloud config set project $1`

Updated property [core/project].

`gcloud info --run-diagnostics`

Property diagnostic passed (1/1 checks passed).

`bq version`

This is BigQuery CLI 2.0.47

All works fine until:

`bq ls`
and script stalls and does nothing

Permissions are fine as same script runs with no problem on VM.

Same with commands like `bq rm`,`bq mk` - the pipeline just stucks.

Any ideas what can be wrong or how to troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: what does `bq ls --debug --format=prettyjson --project_id=REPLACE_WITH_PROJECT_ID` report?

Comment: thanks @JohnHanley for response, tried `deug`, but the same, no output just stalls again, no sure whats happening

Comment: Do other `gcloud` commands work such as `gcloud compute instances list` or `gsutil ls`? The `bq` command uses HTTP/HTTPS transport so if that fails, everything else should fail as well.

Comment: @JohnHanley `gcloud compute instances list` and `gsutil ls` works fine. `Bq ls` still not, can't think about anything what could be wrong?

Comment: No idea at this point. Something with your configuration is broken. As a last resort, reinstall the CLI with the latest version. Make sure that you have the latest version of Python installed.

Comment: @JohnHanley looks like its a bug in Devops ubuntu agent, as scripts stalls if Google Cloud Platform service account have permissions assigned to more than 1 project in GCP

Comment: @norsk If you think it looks like a bug ，you could report it on the [dc forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html). The engineer here will confirm further.